# Is this a relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

> Studying abroad is the wonderful thing **that we must think about**.

Is "that we must think about" a relative clause?
Please explain to me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a relative clause because it has an antecedent in the main clause (all relative clauses have antecedents in their main clauses).

In this particular case, the antecedent of *that we must think about* is the (qualified) noun *the thing*: *the* wonderful *thing* **that** we must think about.

So the relative pronoun *that* simply replaces *the (wonderful) thing* in the subordinate clause **that** (sic!) it introduces.

Comment: Do This relative clause **that we must think about** modify the noun **the (wonderfull) thing** or entire main clause : **Studying abroad is the wonderful thing** ??

Comment: +1 Only "the wonderful thing". Compare: "This one bit of information is the proverbial needle in the haystack that we must search for."  **Needle in the haystack** is the grammatical antecedent, but since it is the subject predicate complement, you could conclude  that **this one bit of information** is to be searched for, inasmuch as **is** equates the two, although it is not the grammatical antecedent.